# Mobile application ? In Asp.net /

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net 2008], i am not getting Mobile template option, is there any sdk required to install mobile template.

Comment: what is this smart device application and what is different from mobile and smart device application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/09/17/tip-trick-asp-net-mobile-development-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx

[What Happened to ASP.Net Mobile Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153051/what-happened-to-asp-net-mobile-web-forms)