# Mobile Application ? In Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net mobile template, when i add mobile form and place textbox, but i am getting erro.
Editing of mobile controls is not supported in the designer.

```
<mobile:Form id="Form1" runat="server">
  <mobile:TextBox ID ="txt" Runat ="server" ></mobile:TextBox>
</mobile:Form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile application ? In Asp.net /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124961/mobile-application-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

The mobile templates in ASP.NET are depricated. It is now recommended that you detect whether or not the request is coming from a mobile phone and use CSS and other elements to render properly on the phone.

Here is a resource to get you started in the right direction:
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application

I hope this helps!